# Wordpress appearance button

Tags: wordpress, color-theme, ux

Is it possible to place an appearance button on  wordpress site. For example to make background bit dark or bit light or other colour. This feature is available on native apps. If it can be done on wordpress site then plz answer how. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're already a member of [Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). That's where this question belongs. Wordpress questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Ok thanks. They didnt let me post for 40 mins. 